# Dojo DataGrid: Filter column - condition: Values in CSV string exist in an Array?

Tags: datagrid, dojo, filtering

I am using Dojo *DataGrid* with dojo '*AndOrReadStore*' so that I can use complex queries on column data.

I have a column, say DocumentTypeIds, in dojo DataGrid that shows comma seperated string of type ids of a document for each document row. Lets say its value is *'5, 6'* among 20 different possible values. These document types are further categorized into 3 categories: *A, B, C*. for example

```
Document Type/name | A B C
---------------------------
5 / finance report | 1 0 0
6 / summary report | 0 1 0
```

Based on choice of A, B and C, I want to filter documents in the grid. For example if user chose C and document type ids are *'5,6'* then I do not want to filter this document. I can filter the possible document type ids based on category in an array that I want to compare this column against. Lets assume the possible values after choosing option C are *[8, 9, 2, 99]*  then my filtering condition needs to be

```
[5,6] in [8,9,2,99]
or 
'5,6' in '8,9,2,99'
```

The problem with first approach is that column values are in CSV format so i dont think i can convert those into array in query. The problem with second approach is that i dont want to find string *'5,6' in '8,9,2,99'* rather i want to find if both *'5' and '6' exist in the '8,9,2,99'* and they may not appear next to each other in *'8,9,2,99'*.

I don't know how to approach this problem as it is very important for me to filter the rows at client side because I want to bring in all rows and let user choose what type of documents they want to see.

```
grid.filter({complexQuery: "DocumentTypeIds: ? "});
```

I appreciate any help.
Thanks